# Run rospy with kivy on android

Tags: python, android, kivy, rospy

How I use rospy on a Kivy project that run on android. If I put python-rospy on requiriments.txt will crash because this library not in pypi, your installation is by sudo apt-get install python-rospy. So, how I use rospy on android by Kivy?

Comment: Simplest solution: copy its source into your app directory, assuming it's a pure python module.